# Resident Evil 5 Infinite Golden Egg

Tags: ps4, resident-evil-5

Playing Resident Evil 5 on the PS4, I came across a couple of people who have infinite gold eggs.

I was able to acquire a golden egg from one of them, originally intending to get the trophy for collecting eggs, and that turned out to be an infinite gold egg. A day or two later, that golden egg no longer had an infinite supply.

I did some searching online, found some answers that mentioned *hacked* eggs. Is there another way to acquire infinite eggs without hacking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you can't get infinite gold eggs without hacking